# Arch Processing Structure Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian, arch-linux

Am attempting to run a node that reads through the ARM processing structure. That said my current arch is aarch64, code below:

```
mypi@raspberrypi:~ $ arch ; uname -m
aarch64
aarch64
```

An individual who has had success running the node currently has armv6l arch. Indicated by the below code:

```
pi@raspberrypi  ~  arch ; uname -m
armv6l
armv6l
```

How do you change the arch type for the Raspberry Pi 4? Am working with the Raspberry 64-bit Debian Bullseye OS. Thought that would automatically be using ARM as the processor? What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help!!

When attempting to launch the node (final step in the process), end up receiving the below error:

```
thetaberry-t3@raspberrypi:~/theta_mainnet/bin $ ./theta start --config=../guardian_mainnet/node
bash: ./theta: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Previously, during the beginning stages of this process, ran into the same error. Ended up wiping the MSD and installing a different version of Raspberry OS, which did the trick. Went from the recommended 32-bit software, to the 64-bit Debian Bullseye Raspberry OS. Am working with a Raspberry Pi 4.

Am running this code based on a Github repository:
https://github.com/kuoyaoming93/guardian-mainnet-guide/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#launch-the-guardian-node

Also, there is a repository for ARM64-based devices. Have already completed all of those steps. The above link is where you are directed for the final launch and stake process.

Comment: This is based on the operating system you have installed, and changing it would require reinstalling.  Why do you think the architecture is the issue though?

Comment: When attempting to launch the node (final step in the process), end up receiving the below error: ```thetaberry-t3@raspberrypi:~/theta_mainnet/bin $ ./theta start --config=../guardian_mainnet/node
bash: ./theta: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error``` Ran into this error during the meat of launching the loan, and switching from 32-bit to 64-bit OS resolved.

Comment: Unsure how to create new line in a comment. The response to the coding command begins at "bash:".

Comment: [Edit] your question with the extra details.

Comment: Linux considers 32-bit ARM (e.g. `armv6l`) and ARM64 (`aarch64`) as entirely separate and independent architectures.  Any given OS install supports one or the other, not both.  So in that sense a Raspberry Pi is like two completely different computers in one package, where you can only use one of them at a time.